# How to uninstall PhotoQt in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

I installed [PhotoQt](https://photoqt.org/), an image viewer software, in Windows 10. Now I want to uninstall it but the app is not listed in Control Panel → Programs → Programs and Features.

[image: Screenshot of search result of "photoqt" in Control Panel → Programs → Programs and Features]

How do I uninstall the app?

Comment: Just delete the installation directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the suggestion to delete the installation directory, PhotoQt is likely not adding an entry to the registry so it will not show up in the list of programs.

**Uninstaller**

It does have an uninstaller `uninstall.exe` located at `C:\Program Files\PhotoQt` which you can run.

**Delete files manually**

You can also delete the files manually. The [GitHub readme for PhotoQt](https://github.com/luspi/photoqt#uninstall) even suggests this.

> ### UNINSTALL
>
> ---
>
> If you want to uninstall PhotoQt, simply run **make uninstall** as root. This removes the desktop file (via *xdg-desktop-menu uninstall*), the icons, the binary file, and the appdata file. Alternatively you can simply remove all the files manually which should yield the same result.

The files for PhotoQt will be located at:

- C:\Program Files\PhotoQt
- %LOCALAPPDATA%\PhotoQt
- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PhotoQt

Comment: If I am not wrong, the quoted text is about uninstalling PhotoQt in Linux. Am I right?

Comment: @RandomPerson - It is indeed about uninstalling the application on Linux